# Wordpress: Adding the category as text - not link

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a ribbon on my posts on the front page, which shows the posts category.

I can add it as text like this (I use the Imbalance theme by WPShower):

```
<?php imbalance2_posted_in(); ?>
```

But how can I just write the `Category Name`, without markup so I can use it in classes and such?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the category of every post with get_the_category(). Below is shown how to get the category of the current post.

```
global $post;
$category = get_the_category( $post->ID ); //OR SOME OTHER ID, DEPENDING ON WHAT YOU WANT
$category_name = $category->name; //GETS THE ORIGINAL NAME, INCLUDING WHITESPACES
$category_slug = $category->slug; //GETS THE SLUG, WHICH WILL BE BETTER TO USE IN CLASSNAMES
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category( $post->ID ); 
?>

<div class="box <?php echo($category->slug); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: How can I put it in here: 
<div class="box <?php $category_slug = $category->slug; ?>"> ... so the category would be a class?

Comment: It doesn't add anything. Can this be done in a loop? It's on the overview/front-page where several posts are shown.

Comment: well, then the problem is in the ID. You need to provide the right ID to get_the_category(). Can you edit your post with the code of how you get and display all your posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `post_class()` to generate a few class names including one for each category.

If you want to do it manually, you can get information on the categories using `get_the_category()` and put the class names together yourself.